# Improving noise reduction of "Lang-Stereotest" image using OpenCV filters

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on denoising an image (more specific a "Lang-Stereotest") using OpenCV filters. I've applied various filters like blur, bilateral, and median blur, but the results are not satisfactory. I'm looking for suggestions to improve the denoising process and achieve better results.

I have used the following processing:

```
# (some code before...)
# Blur
output = cv2.blur(image, (10, 10))
img = Image.fromarray(output, 'RGB')
img.save("images/Filters/" + filePath.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] + " - Blur.jpg")
    
# Bilareal
output = cv2.bilateralFilter(image, 50, 50, 50)
img = Image.fromarray(output, 'RGB')
img.save("images/Filters/" + filePath.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] + " - Bilateral.jpg")

# MedianBlur
output = cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)
img = Image.fromarray(output, 'RGB')
img.save("images/Filters/" + filePath.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] + " - MedianBlur.jpg")

# Weighted
output = cv2.addWeighted(image, 5, image, -5, 128)
img = Image.fromarray(output, 'RGB')
img.save("images/Filters/" + filePath.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] + " - Weighted.jpg")

# Try to combine...
output = ...     # here I want to combine the filters to gain best results..
img.save("images/Filters/" + filePath.split('/')[1].split('.')[0] + " - Best.jpg")
# (some code after...)
```

The results are summarized in the following image:

[image: Filter Comparison]

Of course, the results are far away from perfect and I also know, that there is no hundred percent solution but I think that it should be significantly better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two approaches in mind

## FIRST - Brute-Force approach

Here I manually set a threshold level below which all pixel values are 0 i.e; black

```
ret,th = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, 1)
```

[image]

It looks pretty OK. But we can go further.

## SECOND - Calculative approach

Here I set a threshold based on the **median** value of the gray scale image. This is a method statisticians use for separating data into different classes in data science. So I thought 'Why not try it out for images?'

Here is the code snippet for that:

```
sigma = 0.33
v = np.median(gray)
threshold = (1.0 - sigma) * v
for i in range(gray1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(gray1.shape[1]):
        if (gray[i, j] < threshold):
            gray1[i, j] = 0
        else:
            gray[i, j] = 255

cv2.imwrite('gray1.jpg',gray1)
```

[image]

Yes, it does not look so perfect, but this is where I could go.

From here on it is up to you. You can apply median`filtering followed by some`morphological` operations to attain what you want.

### EDIT

I just copied the `gray` image into `gray1` as reference to be used in the `for` loop.

Here is the complete code for a better understanding:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

filename = '1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray1 = gray

sigma = 0.33
v = np.median(gray)
threshold = (1.0 - sigma) * v
for i in range(gray1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(gray1.shape[1]):
        if (gray[i, j] < threshold):
            gray1[i, j] = 0
        else:
            gray[i, j] = 255

cv2.imwrite('gray1.jpg',gray1)
```

Hope this helped!!!!!!

:)

Comment: Thanks! Could you maybe post your complete code? Because I think that I read in the image in a different way, so `gray[i, j]` doesn't work... I would be glad, if you could post your complete code :)

Comment: Thanks, on some other "Lang Stereotest" a shape gets lost because it's a bit transparent, do you know a solution for that? :/

Comment: @Niklas Oh yes I do. Try the following: `equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)`

Comment: @Niklas If you are not satisfied try this one also : `clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=29.0, tileGridSize=(3,3))` followed by 
`cl = clahe.apply(gray)`. Then `cv2.imshow('CLAHE output', cl)`

Comment: Mhh, this doesn't work that well... If I build that in either the picture stays noisy or some shapes gets lost... :D (also after playing around with the parameters...)

Comment: I think that the settings for clipLimit and tileGridSize are way too hard, but I also can't find better settings :D

Comment: @Niklas Well its a compromise. It clearly depends on the images you use. If you had a better collection of images it would work.

Comment: Can you remove the discussion into a Chat? I have too less reputation and would talk to you a bit more :D

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to create a chat room. In order to do so we have to chat a bit more so that the option of moving conversation to chat room pops up. If it does we can move it to the chat room

Comment: For me the optin already pops up but I don't have enough reputation :D

Comment: Let's chat some more until I get that option :D:D:D:D

Comment: I just plus 1'ed your question to get enough reputation

Comment: Now I have 15 reputation and this is still too less... :/

Comment: I am still working on the problem, so in case I get a better result I will update my answer :) Cheers!!!. Do upload more images if you have :D

Comment: Okay, [here](https://picload.org/image/rooiilia/testimage.jpg) you can see my (self created) test image and [here](https://picload.org/image/rooiilil/removednoisetestimage.jpg) you can see my result. As you can see the left bottom stick man isn't recognized well (I know that it's a really hard picture but it would be awesome, if you could improve the method)! And again: Thank you really much!!!

Comment: I will give it a try :D

Comment: Is there an other way, how we can communicate, without extend the discussion in the comments even more? :D

Comment: And where do I get ur gmail address from? :D

Comment: @Niklas jeru92@gmail.com

Comment: Ok, i sent u a mail :)

Comment: I've come across the paper before. But to me implementing it from scratch is tiresome, it would take a lot of time. I already have my hands full. You could try `cv2.fitEllipse()` after performing edge detection.....

Comment: Why don't we write per email? :D

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to your second image.

I performed **histogram equalization** of the gray scale image as mentioned in the comments:
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)

[image]

I then applied **binary threshold** followed by **dilation**:

```
ret,th = cv2.threshold(equ, 50, 255, 0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, 3)
```

[image]

To reduce noise and spores in the image:

```
close = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, 3)
```

[image]

I inverted the image followed by **morphological close**:

```
ret,th1 = cv2.threshold(close, 50, 255, 1)
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
opened = cv2.morphologyEx(th1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel1, 3)
```

[image]

I then performed **morphological dilation**:

```
dd = cv2.morphologyEx(opened, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel1, 3)
```

[image]

This is the maximum I could get to.

Now you can find contours and eliminate the small dots falling below a certain area.

:)

Comment: Wow, this one is sick! :o